# Firebase Authentication not working with Cordova

Tags: firebase, cordova

I am trying to build an application using Cordova that has Firebase to authenticate users, and manage with photo uploading.

I built the application for web first, then have ported it over to Cordova and am trying to get it to work.

I have tried multiple methods:

- Following the Firebase instructions found on their website
- Using no plugins
- Using a plugin that is quite old that didn't want to install...

Still isn't working, I have researched this for days and still am yet to find a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a gif of me showing the issue, I push the Sign In button, and nothing happens, no error nothing. Nothing appears in the console on X-Code ether...
[image: Demonstrating Question Issue]

Here is my code

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here" />
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <!-- Firebase CDNs -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Atkinson+Hyperlegible&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ArtConnect</title>
    <!-- FB local code -->
    <script src="app/fb/fb_init.js"></script>
    <script src="app/auth/auth_handler.js"></script>
    <script src="app/fb/fb_uploadHandler.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML IO -->
    <script src="app/html/html_io.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">ArtConnect <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" onclick="ui.show('form')">Upload ArtWork</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<body>
    <div id="login">
        <h2>Welcome to ArtConnect</h2>
        <hr>
        <h4>Please login below</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="auth.login()"><i class="bi bi-google"></i> Login with Google </button>
    </div>
    <div id="welcomePage">
        <h2>Welcome, <span id="clientNAME"></span></h2>
        <hr>
        <h4>Your shared artwork</h4>
        <div id="card-container"></div>

    </div>
```

Authentication Code

```
  login: function() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(_user) {
            if (_user) {
                auth.handleSuccess(_user, _user.uid)
                console.log('already logged in...')
                loggedin = true;
            } else if (!_user) {
                if (_provider == google) {
                    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
                        .then(function() {
                            provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
                            console.log("fb_auth | Starting Authentication process", "info")
                            return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(result) {
                                    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                                    let fb_result = result.user;
                                    auth.handleSuccess(fb_result.uid, fb_result)
                                    console.log("auth.login | Authentication Process Successful", "info")
                                    loggedin = true;
                                    $('#landingPage').fadeOut();
                                })
                                .catch(function(error) {
                                    // Handle Errors here.
                                    var errorCode = error.code;
                                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                                    console.log("fb_auth | Error: " + errorMessage, "warn")
                                });
                        })
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening due your if statement

```
...
loggedin = true;
    } else if (!_user) { 
        if (_provider == google) { // <-- _provider is undefined
            firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

Perhaps you intended for it to be `provider`? If so, then the if statement is reduntant. It will always be a `GoogleAuthProvider` due to your definition. In general, I would also recommend using `===` instead of `==` for checking for equality, unless you know what you are doing and really do want to use `==`. You can find a comparison of the two [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: Thanks for that, I have fixed that mistake - but still no luck, any other ideas? I have tried removing the Auth State check first before the google sign in code, but still haven't found success

Comment: What about the `google` variable that you are referencing in the check? How is that defined?

Comment: Yeah, since gotten rid of that - firing the application up in the simulator and opening Safari I now get this error: ```fb_auth | Error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.```